# Simple C++ .dll called with pinvoke; Works for me, but no one else

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I do not know anything about C++, but I figured out enough to get a .dll written for a specific purpose, because there was some code I could not get C# to do.

So I created this DLL using Visual Studio 2013 -> Win32 Project -> Dynamic Link Library as the type, selected "Empty Project", etc.

Now I go over to my C# program and I have pinvoke sections to call this dll by name (`Legacy.dll`). I compile the DLL from C++, and copy/paste it from the /release folder to the /bin/release and /bin/debug folder of my C# application, and run the C# application.

It works fine. I have no issues.

However, when I send the files - the .dll and the .exe to other people, it tells them it cannot find the very same DLL. But it is clearly there, it is clearly working for me....

So what could be the problem? I am compiling both the C# program and the DLL to 32-bit.

## UPDATE

The problem was that my users had the C++ libraries, but it had been sneakily updated to need the 2013 ones, which did not appear in my first search. I had to do an EXPLICITLY specific search to find this.

Comment: how did you reference the dll ?

Comment: what relative path does the c# app look in?

Comment: I am not sure. I simply reference the name of the file. `[DllImport("Legacy.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` - it has not given me any trouble, just other people.

Comment: I assume this means it expects the .dll to be in the same folder as the `.exe`

Comment: Try using static link?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by static link.

Comment: You can choose 'Static linking' in project options, so your dll will not depends on MSVC++ Runtime (MSVC Runtime has many versions)

Comment: Is this in the VC++ or the VC# project?

Comment: It is saying it physically CANNOT find the .dll file, not that it isn't working.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried that and it just made the entire thing invalid. Pinvoke didn't seem to work the same way with a .lib as with a .dll.

Comment: It would help if you showed code and verbatim error messages. The usual cause of your symptoms is that the target machine is missing the CRT resist.

Comment: Don't let yourself get confused by damphat's suggestions. Static linking isn't an option here, since you're calling native code from managed code. Static linking is only an option when calling native code from other native code (unless he was referring to the static runtime library for the DLL file).

Comment: @Mario Don't you think he write a DLL that dependent on a version of msvcrt.dll, so when he send that dll to his friend, the dll cannot be run?

Answer (score 2):

What's your operating system? Are you running a 32 bit or a 64 bit version of Windows? For .NET programs to load 32 bit native DLLs you'll have to ensure that you set the architecture of your .NET project to "32 bit" as well. By default it's on "Any CPU", which will pick the architecture based on the computer running the program. If you run the program on a 64 bit system, it will expect the native DLL to be 64 bit as well (which will cause the problem).

Comment: I have tried it on Windows XP, Vista, 7, all 32 bit. Also 7 64 bit, 8 64 bit, and 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: I have explicitly set it to x86.

Comment: Okay, that's odd then. Any special characters in paths or filenames or anything like that? What happens if you distribute the program using OneClick?

Comment: @Mario Bitness errors do not lead to not found errors. You get Not a valid Win32 image

Comment: Hm right, haven't used it in ages. Unfortunately can't be dependency errors either. Really interesting and no idea what it might be then. :(

Comment: I don't think that would return anything like "file not found" either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds silly, but are you checking for the DLL in your C# program? (Sometimes users can be... 'interesting')

For example:

```
void Initialize()
{
   var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Legacy.dll");

   if(!File.Exists(path))
   {
     // Alert the user that the accompanying DLL is missing...
   }
}
```

Other than that I would check architecture. Are you on 32-bit while they are on 64-bit OSes?